# Reading from and writing to a Notepad in java

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a String of text in a notepad like this

Text in a NotePad:

```
date amount intrest tenure debitamount name address state city zipcode phone altphone mailid refaddress ref  refphoneno emptype employment


12/11/1987 12345 3.5 144 32456 durga f rao 456 under road
dallas dl 2435 2222-22-2222 2222-22-2222 durgafrao@gmail.com
165 nala road raj 22-22-22-2222 it 12
15/05/1986 2345 6.4 144 45789 rama k nand 789 residensy  
newyork ny 2222-22-2222 2222-22-2222 ramaknand@yahoomail.com
189 ring road hen  22-22-22-22-2222 it 12
16/12/1985 1234 6.5 144 35265 rama j rao 123 dura residensy meknoor
mn 2222-22-2222 2222-22-2222 ramajrao@orkut.com 891 cing road vinky
22-22-22-2222 it 12
12/11/1987 12345 3.5 144 32456 durga f rao 456 under road dallas dl
2435 2222-22-2222 2222-22-2222 durgafrao@gmail.com 165 nala road raj
22-22-22-2222 it 12


         out put should be like below
in between name and address single space and all other double space


12/11/1987  12345  3.5  144  32456  durga f rao  456 under road
dallas  dl  2435  2222-22-2222  2222-22-2222  durgaao@gmail.com
165 nala road  raj  22-22-22-2222  it  12
15/05/1986  2345  6.4  144  45789  rama k nand  789 residensy  
newyork  ny  2222-22-2222 2222-22-2222  ramaad@yahoomail.com
189 ring road  hen  22-22-22-22-2222  it  12
16/12/1985  1234  6.5  144  35265  rama j rao  123 dura residensy  meknoor
mn  2222-22-2222  2222-22-2222  ramajo@orkut.com  891 cing road  vinky
22-22-22-2222  it  12
12/11/1987  12345  3.5  144  32456  dura f rao  456 under road  dallas  dl
2435  2222-22-2222  2222-22-2222  durga@gmail.com  165 nala road  raj
22-22-22-2222  it  12
```

I want my output should be  like below
In between name and address single space and all other double space?

I wrote the below code,but I'm not able to get desired ouput

Could any one Help me?

Code which i tried:

```
public static String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");


    public static void main(String args[]){
        FileWriter iWrite=null;

         try {
             iWrite = new FileWriter("C:/Documents and Settings/pavan/My Documents/output.txt");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 

        try {
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/pavan/My Documents/input.txt"));

        for(String lines1:lines){

            iWrite.write(lines1);

            iWrite.write(newLine);
        }
        iWrite.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Consider using `PrintWriter` instead of `FileWriter`.

Comment: Please provide the full info in your question, do not post a link outside SO, instead post the expected and the actual output from your program. Also, maybe you need to use [`String#format`](http://goo.gl/SauwK) in your `iWrite.write` statement.

Comment: You will have problem reading fields with whitespaces unless there is a specification of the input format available.

Answer (score 0):

This smells a homework problem so I'm not thinking of an optimal solution but here's the sudo code of what you can do if you need to.

Before it, let me assume the data is actually is actually in one single line based upon your header :

> 12/11/1987 12345 3.5 144 32456 durga f rao 456 under road dallas dl 2435 2222-22-2222 2222-22-2222 durgafrao@gmail.com 165 nala road raj 22-22-22-2222 it 12

- create a ArrayList of Arrays aka `ArrayList<String[]>`
- For every line you read, use `split(" ")` or `split("\s")` to split the newline into strings based on the spaces
- Once all the lines are split and stored in the arraylist, you can iterate through the list
- Within the list of string array, you can iterate through the array with a hack
- The hack would be that you are aware at which point you need to add an extra space, so in an array when you reach the specific spot, you can append and extra space. Everywhere else you can append just a single space.

Again, this isn't the optimal solution.

As for your current code, all you are doing is just reading a line and appending a newLine character before writing it back to a file. So all your code is doing is making

> a a a
>
> b b b
>
> c c c

into

> a a a
>
> b b b
>
> c c c

in essence, doing not much.